What's the point in having after=<passive target> when the passive target is not pulled in?
I have read the systemd documentation about special targets and hopefully have understood the most part of it. But I am struggling with the section "Special Passive System Units". In the following citation, I have emphasized the part that I don't understand:

A number of special system targets are defined that can be used to properly order boot-up of optional services. These targets are generally not part of the initial boot transaction, unless they are explicitly pulled in by one of the implementing services. Note specifically that these passive target units are generally not pulled in by the consumer of a service, but by the provider of the service. This means: a consuming service should order itself after these targets (as appropriate), but not pull it in. A providing service should order itself before these targets (as appropriate) and pull it in (via a Wants= type dependency).

My problems:

Lacking definition of the technical terms (probably normally self-explanatory, but I just don't get it):

What exactly is a consuming service (or a consumer of a service), and what is a providing service (or a provider of a service)?

The usage pattern for consuming services

As an example, let's look at the special passive network-pre.target target. Following the recommendation, a consumer of that target should have After=network-pre.target in its unit file, but not Wants=network-pre.target or Requires=network-pre.target.
This means that the startup of the consumer is ordered after the network-pre.target, but only if network-pre.target is pulled in by another unit. If network-pre.target is not pulled in by at least one other unit, the consumer is started at a "random" point in time (because the After=network-pre.target in the consumer's unit file can't effect anything in this case). That's the part I don't understand:
What exactly is the point in wanting to start a consumer after a certain passive target, but then not knowing at all whether that passive target gets activated, and that way again leaving it to chance when the consumer starts?
Besides the documentation linked above, I have read other articles about that subject as well; most of them claim that this passive target is "just a synchronization point", or something like that. But again, if nobody pulls it in, it can't serve as a synchronization point.
During the last years, I have written a few unit files that work as expected, just by following the recommended usage patterns from the docs. However, I'd now like to understand those passive targets at a more fundamental level.
Perhaps there's somebody out there who can shed some light on the part I'm struggling with by giving the simplest possible example.
